# Driverless-Ai Model diagnostics failed - bad operand type for binary abs(): 'nonetype'?

Tags: driverless-ai

[image]

I get the error of "bad operand type for binary abs(): 'nonetype'" from an attempted model diagnostics.  What would produce this kind of error ?  What does it mean ?

Comment: What was the input and settings that caused the error? How could it be reproduced?

Comment: I tried several settings, and it seems it happens randomly.  Maybe the test dataset has some problems.  But what does this mean, literally ?  In what kind of situation does DAI give this kind of error ?